# CSS can neighboring children/content clear each other to stack

Tags: css

Can children (of two side by side parents) be set to clear each other?

Stack says I can't post image yet so...

Here is the fiddle with overlapping: http://jsfiddle.net/vEvYZ/28/ -UPDATED with example

UPDATE: The end result would look like 'events' on a calendar, last content on the bottom of longer previous content ...thats the best way i know to describe what I'm after. Hope that helps.

```
.contain{ 
     height:120px; 
 width:500px; 
 border:thin  solid  #FF0000; 
 overflow:scroll;
}

.row{
  height:100px;
  width:950px; 
}

.parent{ 
    height:100px;
    width:100px; 
    display:inline-block; 
    border-right:thin  solid #666666; 
    border-bottom:thin  solid #666666;
    position:relative;

}


.child{ 
    width:90px; 
    height:20px;
    float:left;

    /*this attempt not working*/
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
 }
```

Comment: `align="left"` is deprecated. you must not use it.

Comment: Ah..good catch, the html was tables before divs, I accidentally left the old table attributes..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may need to re-think the structure of your html. For one, using inline-styles is a bad practice because it can make code difficult to maintain and less readable.

Also, considering the different blocks of color used throughout being content of the `.child` divs, these content areas should probably be separate divs nested within the `.child` divs.

---

So, if I have understood correctly, here is the HTML:

```
<div  class="contain">
    <div  class="row">

        <!-- parent div: -->
        <div class = "parent">
            <div class = "child">
                <div class = "red">
                </div>

                <div class = "yellow">
                </div>

                <div class = "blue">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of parent div -->

        <!-- parent div: -->
        <div class = "parent">
            <div class = "child">
                <div class = "blue">
                </div>

                <div class = "yellow">
                </div>

                <div class = "red">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of parent div -->
    </div> <!-- end of row -->
</div> <!-- end of contain -->
```

...and here is the CSS:

```
    .contain {
        height: 120px;
        width: 500px;
        border: thin solid #FF0000;
        overflow: scroll;
    }

    .row {
        height: 100px;
        width: 700px;
    }
    .parent {
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px; 
        display: inline-block; 
        border-right: thin solid #666666; 
        border-bottom: thin solid #666666;
        position: relative;
    }
    .child {
        width: 90px;
        height: 20px;
        /*float: left; ...don't need this one */
    }

    .red {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
    .yellow {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    .blue {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

---

Also, you don't need to use `float: left` on the `.child` divs, because `display: inline-block` on the `.parent` divs has the same effect.

Here is an interesting link about this:  *http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159806965/how-i-learned-to-stop-floating-and-love-the*

Comment: Intersting approach, but this didn't render as expected.  If the content is longer in box one, then the content in box two should drop be low the overlapping child from box 1

Comment: Hmm, it seems that each color block should have a box the same size to contain it in then, rather than a uniformly sized `.parent` div. Usually when content exceeds its' parent container, there can be formatting side-effects on neighboring elements. Otherwise, you might try to use jQuery to determine the number of child elements with something like `$(".parent").children().length`, and set `top` to that value multiplied by `$(.child).height()` for the next .`child` element.